# 英語が残っている: レビュー|クローズ票

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳, 英語

指摘により一部翻訳されたのですが、まだ英語が残っています。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

下記はどうですか？

> それとも$si‌​teName$のトップページに戻ってQ&Aを再開しますか？

Comment: これどうでしょうか？「もうこのカテゴリにはレビュー待ちの投稿はありません！もっとレビューしますか？他のレビューカテゴリをチェックしてみてください。それとも$siteName$のトップページに戻ってQ&Aを再開しますか？」

Comment: @tomute, 適用しました。

Comment: 修正を確認しましたが、問題が残っていたので、再度質問で指摘しました。